# how to know the geometry of a window, while resizing?

Tags: x11, window

It was last century, I do not remember what we used at the department, some basic X-server running XWindow, or Motif, and while resizing a window, we would see a small widget centred in the window, telling us the current values for position and size of the altered window.  How do we do that, nowadays, with Gnome3 in particular.

I know I can do that **after** resizing, using `xwininfo`, but I would like to see it dynamically.

Or is there a command line tool I can invoke, and set the window size of the target window?  Something like `xkill`, but which wouldn't kill the client, just resize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That window geometry info was usually provided by the window manager.  Some apps still do it on their own, notably some terminal apps that report the width and height in characters during a resize -- which is far more useful than reporting in pixels for that kind of program.  `xfce4-terminal` does this.

I don't know how well the following commands will play with Gnome 3, and I don't have Gnome 3 handy to try them, but they might work.

In a traditional X environment you can use `xev -id <window>` to monitor X events on the specified window.  Those events include `ConfigureNotify` events that report, among other things, the window's position, width, and height.  To show only the interesting geometry-changing events use `xev -id <window> -event structure`.  You'll have to use something like `xwininfo` to discover the window ID to give to `xev`

To resize and/or move a window from the command line, use `wmctrl`.  The `-e` option to `wmctrl` takes an optarg of the form `<gravity>,<posx>,<posy>,<width>,<height>` with certain values reserved to mean "do not change".  To change a window's width and height while keeping its gravity and position unchanged specify `0,-1,-1,<width>,<height>`.  The easiest way to choose the target window for `wmctrl` is to use the `-r :SELECT:` option, but if you happen to know the window ID in advance then you can give that to `-r`, typically with an additional flag like `-i` to specify that the ID should be understood as a numeric ID.

Obviously [`man xev`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xev/) and [`man wmctrl`](https://www.venea.net/man/wmctrl(1)) have all the gory details.

Comment: Solid answer.  If I could recommend one thing it would be to provide some links (static wikis of course) to the man pages that you reference.  Other than that, props to you and enjoy the upvote.

Comment: while I had thought of checking `xev`, I'm very happy you mention `wmctrl`, which I did not know.

Comment: @mariotomo, `xdotool` can also resize windows (and other fancy things)