# Show the window size while resizing

Tags: kde, kwin

The question "[how to know the geometry of a window, while
resizing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518589/how-to-know-the-geometry-of-a-window-while-resizing)"
looked promising, but its single, accepted answer  suggests to use CLI tools
to resize a window to a specific size, so it's not answering my specific
questions:

- Using a modern issue of KDE (KDE 5 in my case), is it possible
  to configure the window manager so that a windowlet is shown,
  showing the instantaneous size (usually in pixels, in characters
  for XTerm and its similar) of the resizing window?
- If yes, how to?

---

Addendum
I checked which display server the system is using: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE ⇒ x11`.

---

Using the method described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709683/164535) I have the following window, no "Display geometry when moving or resizing" option to be clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're on X.org: System Settings -> Window Behavior  -> Movement -> Display geometry when moving or resizing

If you're under Wayland: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443723

Comment: Dear Artem, thank you for your answer. II'm afraid that the KDE version that Suse Tumbleweed places on me there has no such option (please see the edit I made to my question). I think your answer is useful, but not to me (→ +1, not accepted).

Comment: According to the bug report, if I read it correctly, the feature was removed and the new patch which fixes it is yet to be merged.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like recently this topic has been discussed in the KDE community, and currently while waiting for it to be pushed to the mainstream, you can get it in the KDE store for the time being.

Here is the link: https://www.pling.com/p/1833846/

Or you can find it in the Discovery store if using KDE.

Comment: I have installed the script using `Discover` (I've searched for "Window Geometry Information", then I clicked "Install"), then I resized a window: no geometry info. I logged out, X was restarted, I logged in — I _assume_ that KWin read its init stuff — I resized a window and still no geometry info??? Could you please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Never mind, I've correctly activated the script. Unfortunately, it doesn't fulfill my expectations, as it shows the geometry in pixels even for the likes of XTerm, Emacs etc. I have the need for geometry info only when resizing those type of windows, and I need that info in terms of characters.